# ¿Se pueden crear clases de C++ en archivos separados en Sublime Text 3?

Tags: c++, archivo, clase, sublimetext3

básicamente estoy usando C++ en Sublime 3 mediante la configuración presentada en este video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvj0uil-M10.
En Code::Blocks hay una opción que permite crear clases de C++ generando los archivos .h y .cpp, (espero le suenen), la pregunta es si esto se debe hacer manualmente en Sublime, o sí existe una opción predefinida como en Code::Blocks. He creado los archivos .h y .cpp manualmente para hacer esta práctica de composición: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCaxfmcDYjs, los archivos .h no tienen ningún problema, pero  tengo errores en los .cpp y en el archivo principal. Con exactamente el mismo código de los archivos que aparecen en el último video, tengo los siguientes errores:

**Birthday.cpp**

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 1.3s]
```

**People.cpp**

```
C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\ccHZJUNW.o:People.cpp:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `Birthday::printdate()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 1.2s]
```

**main.cpp**

```
C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\ccdsEEjR.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `Birthday::Birthday(int, int, int)'
C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\ccdsEEjR.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `People::People(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Birthday)'
C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\ccdsEEjR.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xa2): undefined reference to `People::printinfo()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 1.2s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['g++.exe', '-o', 'main', 'C:\\cproj\\main.cpp']]
[dir: C:\cproj]
[path: D:\Program Files\Cuminas\Document Express DjVu Plug-in\;C:\Users\usuario\Searches\Documents;C:\MinGW\bin]
```

Me gustaría saber si esto tiene solución o se debe a alguna incompatibilidad irremediable, gracias por su tiempo!.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que cada .cpp que creas debes adjuntarlo al compilador (por ejemplo si usas gcc seria: g++ main.cpp another.cpp -o executable.exe).

Sería un desastre en proyectos grandes, para suerte de nosotros existen algunas herramientas que hacen nuestra vida mas facil, como Cmake o Visual Studio (no conozco mas).

Estas herramientas hacen que puedas configurar mas comodamente la creacion de proyectos.

Te recomiendo que uses Cmake ya que es muy facil de adaptar a tus IDEs y muy facil de aprender (sí, es un lenguaje)